# What would the be reason JQuery has access to DOM but not ExtJS?

Tags: ajax, extjs

I have a Kohana framework which is building ExtJS objects in one view, which in turn loads (via JQuery AJAX) other views inside of it with a this function:

```
function replaceContentOnClick(id, route) {
    $('body').delegate(('#' + id), 'click', function(){
        $.get(route, function(data) {
            $('#region_center .x-panel-body').html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

This is working fine but only when these child views are merely HTML/Javascript/JQuery, but in the child views I cannot get any ExtJS objects to display, even if I render them to DOM elements that exist and to which I can successfully append JQuery elements. It is as if the DOM doesn't exist for ExtJS at that moment.

**The main problem is:** the JQuery code successfully fills the element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#region_center .x-panel-body').html('this is from jquery...');
</script>
```

but the **ExtJS code fails to fill the same element** (an there is no error reported in Firebug/Net panel):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var region_center = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'region_center',
        region: 'center',
        renderTo: '#region_center .x-panel-body',
        margins:'10 10 10 10',
        padding:'10 10 10 10',
        autoScroll:true,
        html: 'this is from ExtJS...'
    });
</script>
```

**What do I have to do so that ExtJS can access the DOM element as JQuery can?**

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you mean that you want to be able to click a link on the page and have an Ext Panel generated and rendered dynamically?  What does Ajax have to do with it?  Do you want the Panel's content to be loaded remotely?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm building a framework using Kohana/PHP and ExtJS, the goal is to enable developers to create modules in PHP which access a PHP singleton class called "Layout_Window" which in turn outputs the Javascript/ExtJS/JQuery to create an application layout based on ExtJS's border layout style with north/south/east/west/center regions each which in turn can contain further ExtJS elements such as grids, forms, tabs, accordion menus.

Comment: My current task is figuring out how the PHP-to-Javascript communication is going to work so that developers can simply work on the PHP level without any knowledge of Javascript/ExtJS, yet are able to dynamically add e.g. items (ExtJS panels) to a accordion menu, or tabs to a tab area, or change the content of another region in the main window layout.

Comment: I'm currently working through the examples/feed-viewer/view.html example in the ExtJS examples, and basically see the solution as: PHP singleton Layout_Window class which is saved in the session and available to all PHP/Kohana views, which will render the base ExtJS/Javascript code once at on the initial page view, and then through methods will call PHP files (Kohana views) via AJAX which manipulate the existing Javascript according to the wishes of the user (e.g. clicking on the header of a panel in an accordion menu will open the panel AND change the center area of the parent layout).

Comment: If anyone knows of existing frameworks which are build along these lines or examples that might be helpful, would appreciate it.

Comment: **More to the point of this question**, I added at the end of this question the JQuery code which *does* have access to the DOM and the ExtJS code which *does not* have access to the DOM. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two bits of code are doing different things.  This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#region_center .x-panel-body').html('this is from jquery...');
</script>
```

...is accessing the DOM node at '#region_center .x-panel-body' and injecting a new innerHTML value.  This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var region_center = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'region_center',
        region: 'center',
        renderTo: '#region_center .x-panel-body',
        margins:'10 10 10 10',
        padding:'10 10 10 10',
        autoScroll:true,
        html: 'this is from ExtJS...'
    });
</script>
```

...is attempting to render **a complete Panel component into itself** (i.e., the `renderTo` config is pointing at the panel with id 'region_center', which is the panel itself).  This makes no sense and will not work.  You can only render components to an existing DOM node -- in this example, there is no existing DOM node with id 'region_center' because the panel is not yet (and cannot be) rendered.

The equivalent code to do exactly what you're doing in jQuery would be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.get('#region_center').child('.x-panel-body').update('this is from Ext...');
</script>
```

Assuming all things are equal in the DOM when this is run, it should execute exactly like your jQuery code.

Now, assuming that your BorderLayout is properly rendered, and it in fact has a center region with id 'region_center', you should be able to add a new panel into it dynamically (make sure the new panel's id is unique).  Note that it would be preferable to go through the Component API (instead of the DOM API) to do this as layout will be managed for you in that case.  E.g., you'd want to do something like:

```
// assuming myCenterPanel is a valid *component* ref (NOT a DOM element):
myCenterPanel.add(new Ext.Panel(...));
myCenterPanel.doLayout();
```

You'd also want to ensure that the center panel has an appropriate layout assigned (via the layout config).  If you simply render the new panel directly to the underlying DOM node instead (as you're trying to do above), it *may* work, but in the long term will probably cause you other issues (again, since you are bypassing Ext's layout manager in that case).

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, I've made a first run at a PHP/Kohana/ExtJS framework to allow developers to manipulate PHP objects which in turn create an ExtJS application underneath, I got it to a point where it was pretty flexible but since I had used JQuery to perform the click handling functionality, it showed its limitations quite quickly, now a bit more knowledgable in ExtJS I'm redoing it without JQuery, my main task now is to be able to (a) load pages via AJAX upon clicks on ExtJS objects, and (b) from those AJAX pages, manipulate the ExtJS which already exist.

Comment: ...the feedviewer example http://dev.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html is a good start, if anyone knows of other ExtJS examples of this type showing how to put together an ExtJS with AJAX loading of (PHP) pages, I would appreciate any links.